# Sharing files between Ubuntu and Windows VM

Tags: virtualbox

This may sound like a stupid question to ask, but I've looked around online and I could not find anything about the topic. All I am wondering is if it would be possible to share files between my Ubuntu machine and a virtual machine of Windows 7. I have seen it done before using Ubuntu as the virtual machine, but I am not sure how I would get it done in the way I described.

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: Are you running Virtualbox or VMware Workstation?

Comment: Hey there. I am currently using Virtualbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is install Install Guest Additions.  Click on Devices --> Install Guest Additions

[image]

Once installed, click on settings --> Shared Folders, and add a folder(s) you want to share.  See images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for doing this! I'll be sure to give this a shot. :)